# Custom Paging in LINQ with C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I was trying to make Custom paging with LINQ. Everything is fine. But the Last page results previous page output values. I know because of this,

```
int skip = Math.Max(AC.rows * (AC.page - 1), 0);  // Doing page -1.
```

But I need to know how can i make the logic purely to work with pagination. Pls someone guide me to do correct logic for this.

**Code**

```
var selectpending = CsA.CsAutoCompletes(AC, searchTerm);
var Tot = selectpending.Count();
int skip = Math.Max(AC.rows * (AC.page - 1), 0);
int totpages = Convert.ToInt32(Tot / AC.rows);

um = selectpending.Skip(skip).Take(AC.rows).ToList();
return Json(new
{
    rows = um,
    records = Tot,
    page = AC.page,
    total = totpages
}
, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: is `AC.page` zero-based or one-based?

Comment: AC.page is one-based. When The first time querying AC.page is as 1.

Comment: In that case it is impossible that `skip` will be -1 at any time as indicated by your comment. Are you sure it is one-based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tot` may not be divisible by `AC.Rows`, so you should do something like `int totpages = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double)Tot)/ AC.Rows);`